# Prevent IE showing two DIVS during half a second on load

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div id="block1">
some text
</div>
<div id="block2">
some more text
</div>
```

And a piece of jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     $('block1').css('display', 'block');
     $('block2').css('display', 'none');
});
```

In theory, this should show block1 and hide block2. In practice, IE shows both DIVs during half a second before showing only the good one (block1). This doesn't happen on Chrome, Firefox, etc...

I can't add style="display: block;" and style="display: none;" directly in the HTML code because it's dinamically generated.

Is there any alternative using jQuery to make this work in every browser?

Comment: How are you adding the jquery if the html is not under your control?

Comment: You could use straight JS for it, the flash is because it's taking the time to parse the jQuery library before it can use it. Even with the JS approach you're still likely to have a flash of sorts (albeit shorter) as the script still has to execute client side before the behaviour will hide it, also, you could run into issues where the script runs before the page has loaded fully which would be even worse.

Comment: why not add dynamically both blocks as hard-coded display:none, and display:block on document ready the one you want? that way they never both show at the same time

Comment: Why can't you just do this with css?

Comment: `$('block1')` and `$('block2')` should be `$('#block1')` and `$('#block2')`

Comment: What do you have access to? Stylesheets? JavaScript before page load? JavaScript after page load? The first 2 can control styles very early.

Comment: Thanks to all. @Huangism solution did the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using css in a style sheet to hide both divs first, and use jquery to show it like the way you are doing it now

OR

You can just make the entire body not visible in css and use jquery to alter visibility after everything is ready to be shown.

If you have control over the output div code, you can always output them as display none and show the correct one only. Lots of options but I don't know what you can/cannot do